# 「彼は3年前に死んだ」vs. 「彼は3年前に死んでいる」

Tags: nuances

Compare

> 彼は3年前に死んだ。
> He died three years ago.

with

> 彼は3年前に死んでいる。

**Question:** Is the nuance between these two sentences something like (i) the first one implies the death is final and overwith, while (ii) the second one implies that the death still "lingers on" in its effect on everyone?

Answer (score 4):

I would personally translate these as:

> 彼は3年前に死んだ -- "He died three years ago"
> 彼は3年前に死んでいる -- "He has been dead for three years"

The first is talking about a past event (him dying).  The second is talking about his current state (he is currently dead, and has been for a while).

I don't know that either one really has any particular implications about the effect of the death on other people, though.